# Android Layout Help - rows with static height and covered background image

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, cover

I'm new to Android development. I've searched and tried almost everything that I've found but I couldn't managed to create the layout below. Basiciliy it'll be rows with background image and text middle-left aligned. I want all rows to be static height and background image to be covered (like this: [css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover)).

[image: layout that I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear but you could try a `LinearLayout` (vertical) with inside
a `RelativeLayout` with fixed height for each items. In `RelativeLayout` aa
`ImageView` with match_parent for background of item with scale type at `center` and a `TextView` for text with padding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_alert_1"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blabla"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_alert_2"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blabla"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_alert_1"
            android:scaleType="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blabla"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Documentation about Android scale type: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html